# recovery for deleted composer.json and composer.lock

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect

I mistakenly deleted `composer.json` and `composer.lock` from my Magento ecommerce site and now my site will not respond. How can i solve that please?

I tried reinstalling but still the site will not respond.

thanks

Comment: Did you use Git?

Answer (score 1):

If you just deleted the two files and they are present in your Git, then `git status` will tell you what to do:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    composer.json
    deleted:    composer.lock
```

Then run:

```
git checkout -- composer.json
git checkout -- composer.lock
```

and check again. Git status will not show the files as deleted any more.